# Overwriting CSS styles for IE8, multiple class selectors

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, stylesheet

I am trying to overwrite some style rules specifically if the user's browser is IE8. In my `<!doctype html>` I have these rules:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Which will add the defined classes to the `<html>` tag after detecting an IE browser.

The block I want to target has a class of `.social`. 
To overwrite .social for IE8, what is the correct selectors to use in the .css? I've tried `.social.no-js.lt-ie9`, `no-js.lt-ie9`, and just `.no-js.lt-ie9`. Does the order in which I list the classes matter? Does it matter if the classes are not direct descendants of each other? Nothing I do seems to be overwriting the actual .social in IE8. Any hints?

Below is what I have so far...

```
.social {
    background: url('../images/thanks-paper.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 540px;
    margin: 10px 0 40px -333px;
    padding: 0 0 0 310px;
    position:relative;
}

.no-js.lt-ie9.social {
  background:url('../images/thanks-paper.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  height:540px;
  margin:10px 0 40px -400px;
  padding-bottom:0;
  padding-left:382px;
  padding-right:0;
  left:8px;
  position:relative;
}
```

And here is how the page is currently set up...

```
<html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en">
  <head> ... </head> 
    <body> ... 
      <div class="social"> ... </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just have leave the classes as is, then add/remove css rules by wrapping the `<link rel="stylesheet" ...>` tags with the conditionals?

Answer (score 1):

Use this to target IE8 and below:

```
.lt-ie9 .social {
    margin-left: -400px;
    padding-left:382px;
    left:8px;
}
```

The class `.no-js` is supposed to be used in conjunction with a library like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com). By removing the class using javascript it serves as an indication as to whether JS is enabled or not. You can use `.no-js` is your CSS to target browsers with javascript *disabled*.

Also, note the spaces between classes. When classes are written without spaces (like `.lt-ie9.social`) you're actually trying to look for an element with *all* those classes. So `.no-js.lt-ie9.social` is trying to find an element with every one of those classes.